# how to increment a sequence number while triggering data from one table to another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I want to write a trigger to transfer some columns of all inserted rows in a table to another table while incrementing the maximum number in a sequence number field in the destination table. this field is not auto increment but is a primary key field.

What I used to do was find the max sequence no in destination table, increment and then insert the new value. This worked fine if data is inserted row at a time. But when many rows are inserted from a single query, how can I increment the sequence number? Sample problem follows:

```
insert into [mssql].mssql.dbo.destination_table (name,seq_no)
select name,?
from inserted
```

even few thousand rows can be inserted at once.

seq_no is part of a composite primary key. So for example if data is inserted under different name seq_no will be different. (This requirement should be considered when I can increment the seq_no without considering its part in the primary key)

Comment: Please specify the version of SQL Server? Also can you describe what you expect to happen if two people try to insert multiple rows at the same time?

Comment: using sql server2005. i want the sequence no to increment by one each time. i thought i don't have to consider multiple insertion to the source table as with its primary key SQL won't allow multiple insertions to the same table till the first transaction is over.. correct me if i've missed your point.

Comment: To clarify, the seq_no will have a separate running number depending on name? For example, "Bob" may be running 10, 11, 12, etc., but "Mary" may be running 99, 100, 101?

Comment: yes @alextansc it will be separate running numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got your problem, try this

```
insert into [mssql].mssql.dbo.destination_table (name,seq_no)
select name, x.MaxSeq + row_number() over (order by name)
   from inserted, (select Max(seq_no) As MaxSeq From source_table) x
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but 2 problems, have to increment the seq number of the destination table not the source. and even if i change the source table to destination table in last line it would only add once to existing max sequence number. so all other inserted rows have the same sequence number

Comment: yes change source_table to destination_table and that should be fine because this insert is one record at a time.

lets say initially max seq in destination is 5.
Insert a row with 6 as seq.
When its time for next insertion, max seq will be 6 so when u insert 6 + 1 = 7
Every time it will increase by 1, I dont see the problem here, or did I not get the problem right?

Comment: the problem is that insert is not one row at a time it will be many rows sometime few thousand rows. yes this will work if it's only one row.